# Style History Back Button

Tags: javascript, css, button, styles

I have the following Javascript in order to create a back button to the previous page.

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
function goBack() { window.history.back() }
// ]]></script>
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

I want to style my button by changing the background colour and text colour. However, I am not very experienced. I have searched but cannot find out if this is even a possibility.

Comment: Try googling "style button css" - and give the button a type="button" too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Class` to achieve what you are looking for.

After using class, you need to style it to add background, padding, etc.
For instance,

```css
.buttonBg {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="goBack()" class="buttonBg">Go Back</button>
```

**[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fc9dosg5/)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is spot on. Problem solved!

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are welcome :)